# Not getting SendEmail property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to send email for forget password while trying the below code

```
        [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordModel Model)
              {
                   MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(Model.Username);

                   if (ModelState.IsValid)
               {
                   SendEmail.SendResetEmail(currentUser);
                 }
          return View();
       }
```

SendEmail is not coming as a property can any one provide the details which namespace we have to used to get this SendEmail.

I used the name spaces System.net.mail and System.web.mail but no use

Thanks
Bhanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like `SendEmail.SendResetEmail` in any of the aforementioned namespaces.
`SendResetMail` should be a static method in a class called `SendEmail` which handles the email operations.

Please find out where you have defined that class and import that namespace. Or if you have copied the code from another project, please copy that class also to your project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be som proprietary code you are looking for. The BCL very seldom uses procedural programming (static methods on a type) how ever sending a mail in .NET is oretty easy:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("info@foo.bar.com");

message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient1@somewhereelse.com"));

message.Subject = "This is the subject";
message.Body = "This is the body/content of the mail message";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); //might have to provide details here depending on the server setup
client.Send(message);
```